# Copy A1 value from google sheet and copy to first empty row in column B of other google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When copying the value it is sent to last row plus one of the entire worksheet, what do I need to edit so that it sends the value to specifically the first empty row of column B?

```
function A1toFirstEmptyRow() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Página1');
  var SData = ss.getRange('Página1!A1').getValues();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Página1');
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1,2,SData.length,SData[0].length).setValues(SData);
}
```

In blue would be the correct location to save and in red the current location being saved:

[image]

The script is currently parsing all columns, so if there are values in row 5 of column A, the value will be placed in row 6 of column B.

I would like it to be placed on row 2 in this example I cited. Because row 2 is the first row that is empty of column B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  function copyLastToLast() {
    var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
    var sh = sss.getSheetByName('Página1');
    var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB');
    var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Página1');
    var r=1;
    while(ts.getRange(r,2).getValue()) {
      r++;
    }
    ts.getRange(r,2).setValue(sh.getRange(1,1).getValue());
  }
```